# When I review posts, and want to make an edit, but the edit queue is full

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

When I review posts, and want to make an edit, but the edit queue is full, should I just skip it?

Comment: That's what I do. One can't pick "No action needed" because action is needed, so I Skip. (Assuming this is either Late Answers or First Posts)

Comment: How will it find it later?

Comment: There's not really much to do aside wait. You can open the question in a new tab and come back to it in a little while

Comment: You can find it if you want to by looking in your review [history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history) and marking "show skipped reviews" at the bottom. But chances are someone else will have reviewed it Or you can just bookmark it, if you want to edit it later.

Comment: What do you mean by “the edit queue is full” exactly?

Comment: @SecurityHound When <2K tries to edit a post when the queue is full, they get a little red pop-up notification saying just that. The UI is denying opening up the post for editing. It's like the edit option is removed and replaced with the little red notification. We get the same of [every post on meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdHYz.png), just a different message.