# Review queues edit

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I am new to the 500 reputation bracket.

I was reviewing some questions and answers. Sometimes I was seeing something small to fix. Something like grammar, spelling or code formatting. So I did some edits. Some of them could not be queued because there was already another edit queued.

Is there any way to see beforehand if the edit queue is full? Either way it would be great if the edit button were to gray out if there were an edit queued.

Comment: Related, but a bug report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411050/in-the-first-questions-queue-you-can-choose-edit-as-action-even-when-the-edi

Comment: As to the [meta-tag:support] portion of your question of "Is there any way to see beforehand if the edit queue is full?": You can open the post in a normal question page, which should display that there's a pending edit. It's not a great solution, but it should provide you with the information you're looking for.

Comment: This is a common request. What is the canonical meta question?

Comment: Related (not duplicates): *[Reviewing while edit queue full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350377/reviewing-while-edit-queue-full)* and *[When I review posts, and want to make an edit, but the edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397660/)*

Comment: Does [Why doesn't SO block the edit option if the edit queue is already full and why can't we have a read access to the edit queue in review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416102/11407695) look like a good candidate, @PeterMortensen?